# function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase cloud functions.I am trying to build Api for react-application  in Express , firebase-admin SDK, there were happy days everything was working as expected, until I try to send notification on whenever post is liked ? `functions.https` is working but `functions.firestore.document` is ignored for some reason, I am attaching `ss` of terminal

[image]

Anybody Please help me out to troubleshoot who can I trigger functions.firestore

```
exports.api = functions.region('asia-east1').https.onRequest(app)

// -----------------notifications triggers------------
//on like send notification
exports.sendLikeNotification=functions.region('asia-east1').firestore.document('/likes/{docId}').onCreate(sendLikeNotification)
//on dislike delete notification
exports.deleteLikeNotification=functions.region('asia-east1').firestore.document('/likes/{docId}').onDelete(deleteLikeNotification)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to run the emulators first and then run `firebase serve`. And when running the emulators it looks like you don't have java installed. What do you get when you run `java --version` ?

Comment: Yes I have not java installed yet!

Comment: Have you installed java? Are you still facing same issue after installing java? Meanwhile can you try running `firebase init` and [`firebase init emulators`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#:~:text=firebase%20init-,emulators,-Once%20an%20emulator) to setup Emulator suite?

Comment: Does my above comment help you?